# How can I wrap text in a text box in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I have a text box, and when I enter text it flows as one long line. How can I make it wrap? There is a video on YouTube, but it is not clear what the text to enter is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Select the shape(s) where you want the label to wrap
- Select the "text" panel in the right-hand panels
- Tick the "word wrap" option. (If "word wrap" doesn't appear then  check `resizable` under Style → Property and then it should appear.)

[image: The text format panel in diagrams.net]

Comment: Choose: Format->Style  then add html=1;whiteSpace=wrap  (Case sensitive!)

Comment: In the latest version online it's just select the node, on the menu do Text->Word Wrap, that's it.

Comment: @David, don't you think it's better if word wrap is enabled by default?

Comment: FYI - The newer properties access to this is only for nodes, this is not true of free floating text areas. However the 'Style' method with `html=1;whiteSpace=wrap` does work for text areas.

Comment: can you please tell me where is `word wrap` present ?

Comment: *Edit Style* with the right click menu and type that into the box of poorly formatted text.  Super simple, super obtuse.....

Comment: @oucil uncheck "autosize" in properties for the text area/label. This enables the missing "word wrap" checkbox for text labels.

Answer (score 2):

Since the above answer did not work for me, I am answering here.

1. After clicking on a text box, select the right hand menu tab called **STYLE**.
2. Under this menu tab, expand the **Property | Value** submenu (see screenshot).
3. Click on the **Text Overflow** option that is currently selected (likely **hidden** or **visible**).
4. Select the **fill** or **width** option and voila - it should wrap properly!

[image: Screenshot of which parameter to select]

Comment: Nope, fill just behave like hidden for me.

Comment: @Machado Are you trying to wrap text *within* a box as stated in the original question? If yes, then your answer will be to set "Text Overflow" to "Fill". If your text is still partially hidden inside a too small box, you need to drag the edges of the text box as needed. This is done in order to give enough space for displaying the entire text. The box does not autosize so you need to do this by yourself.

Comment: The answer checked as "correct" by the OP solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The text box is resizable under Style → Property.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was checking the box `resizable` under *Style* → *Property*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a **text label** rather than a **shape**, the way to do this is to disable the "autosize" checkbox in the hidden properties. This enables the "word wrap" checkbox to appear in the text panel in the UI for text labels.

[image: autosize property checkbox, unchecked]

Before:

[image: word wrap checkbox not available]

After:

[image]